# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined at new ZoomIndicator

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I did install the plugin as explained in https://github.com/tumerorkun/react-leaflet-zoom-indicator but I get this error while using this code

```
import { ReactLeafletZoomIndicator } from 'react-leaflet-zoom-indicator'

<Map
    map={this.refs.mapRef}
    center={[51,10]}
    length={4}
    onClick={(e)=>{this.handleClick(e)}}
    ref="mapRef"
    zoom={5.5}
>
    <ReactLeafletZoomIndicator head='zoom:' position='topleft' />
    <TileLayer
          /*Links for background map*/
    />
          {newLocation}
          {existingLocations}
</Map>
```

It fails at this line

```
    _this.map = context.map || _this.props.leaflet.map;
```

in react-leaflet-zoom-indicator.js from node_modules

Comment: Looks like `leaflet` and `react-leaflet` are not in **dependencies** for this package. They only in the **devDependencies**. Did you install them yourself?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!!!!I did import them in file by    "import {Map, Marker, ... } from 'react-leaflet' " if you mean that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ReactLeafletZoomIndicator does not have the context set hence the property map is undefined. Try this:

```
import { ReactLeafletZoomIndicator } from 'react-leaflet-zoom-indicator'

const ReactLeafletZoomIndicatorWithContext =  = withLeaflet(ReactLeafletZoomIndicator);

<Map
    map={this.refs.mapRef}
    center={[51,10]}
    length={4}
    onClick={(e)=>{this.handleClick(e)}}
    ref="mapRef"
    zoom={5.5}
>
    <ReactLeafletZoomIndicatorWithContext head='zoom:' position='topleft' />
    <TileLayer
          /*Links for background map*/
    />
          {newLocation}
          {existingLocations}
</Map>
```

v2 of react-leaflet requires this. See [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/context.html).

By wrapping your custom component using the withLeaflet(), it will get the Leaflet context object injected in its props.